# Change href from anchor tag without class nor id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an event plugin that links all of the schedule text to the main event page, like this:

```
<td><a href="http://apavtcongresso.staging.wpengine.com/event/congresso-apavt-2018/">Chegada dos primeiros congressistas</a></td>
```

However, I need to change the link for specific anchor tags to redirect to other pages and I can't add id or classes to the `<a>` element.

Is there a way to change the href attribute by finding the text inside `<td></td>`, which in this case is "Chegada dos primeiros congressistas"?

I know I can change the text itself by using `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Example 1', 'Change to Example 2');` but don't know how to do it to change attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use jQuery and its `:contains`, which allows you to concisely select elements with a particular content:

```js
const a = $('a:contains(Chegada dos primeiros congressistas)');
a.prop('href', 'https://foo.bar');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://apavtcongresso.staging.wpengine.com/event/congresso-apavt-2018/">Chegada dos primeiros congressistas</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, if you don't want to require a big library, iterate manually through the document's `a`s which match the selector:

```js
const a = Array.prototype.find.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('td > a'),
  a => a.textContent === 'Chegada dos primeiros congressistas'
);
a.href = 'https://foo.bar';
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://apavtcongresso.staging.wpengine.com/event/congresso-apavt-2018/">Chegada dos primeiros congressistas</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Would you mind helping me in other issue? So for the `<a>` that have the `href="http://apavtcongresso.staging.wpengine.com/event/congresso-apavt-2018/"`, how can I disable them? Is there a way to find a href attribute and remove/disable it?

Comment: See the snippets - like your question asks, it changes the `href` to something else  (`"https://foo.bar"`). If you want to remove the `href`s entirely, that's different from just changing the `href`s

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href = 'http://newlink.com'
```

```html
<td><a href="http://apavtcongresso.staging.wpengine.com/event/congresso-apavt-2018/">Chegada dos primeiros congressistas</a></td>
```

Comment: This will only work if the `<a>` in question happens to be the first in the document - it makes no attempt to verify that the chosen `<a>` is the desired one. (also, if you only wanted to select the first matching element, much better to use `querySelector`, which returns a single element, than to use a method that returns a collection and select the first element in the collection)